# Toggle the visibility of multiple divisions with multiple classes using checkboxes that represent each class

Tags: jquery, html, css

This is my first time posting here and I'm not too experienced...

There are a lot of similar questions asking how to show/hide divs based on checkbox selectors; what's throwing me is that I have div's with multiple classes, and if any of these classes relevant checkboxes are selected, I want the div to show.

For example, let's say I want a page to show all movies that correspond to checkboxes that have been selected for a range of actors. Multiple actors can be in a singe movie, and I want all movies to show provided at least one actor is selected. My approach so far has been to:

1. Place each movie in a separate div
2. Add the actor name as a class to each movie div
3. Create a checkbox for each actor, with a value that matches the corresponding div class:
4. Set each div class to display none
5. Use JQuery to show a div if it's still hidden

Initially I tried to achieve this using toggle() but I ran into the problem of the display: state reversing if two actors from the same movie were selected.

Next I simply tried coding:

```
if ($("." + inputValue).is(':hidden')){
$("." + inputValue).show()};
```

To overcome the problem of checking a checkbox and then unchecking it but having the movie remain, I've added an else statement to hide the element if it's already showing.. but now I have the same problem that I had with toggle()

I've added the code below - if you select either Brad Pitt or Angelina Jolie you'll see 'Mr and Mrs Smith' display. The problem is, if you then select the other actor/actress then it will disappear again. I might be wrong, but it appears that changing the display property for a div class changes the property for all other classes attached to that div (Which makes sense as this would avoid collisions)

Is the only fix here to have an ID for every single movie and to instead check if the movie is already showing? (I have a lot of movies and not that many actors so this would result in a lot more CSS code)

```css
.BradPitt {
  display: none
}

.AngelinaJolie {
  display: none
  }
```

```html
<div>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="actorCheckbox" value="BradPitt"> Brad Pitt </label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="actorCheckbox" value="AngelinaJolie"> Angelina Jolie </label>
</div>

<div class = "BradPitt AngelinaJolie">Mr and Mrs Smith</div>



<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

  var showElements = function() {

        var inputValue = $(this).attr("value");
        
        if ($("." + inputValue).is(':hidden')){
        $("." + inputValue).show()
      }else{
        $("." + inputValue).hide()
        };


  }

  $( "input[type=checkbox]" ).on( "click", showElements );  
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is easiest if you always hide all movies first, and then show those again that correspond to the value of one of the checked checkboxes. That saves you from having to deal with “conflicting” checkbox states.

```css
.movie {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="actorCheckbox" value="BradPitt"> Brad Pitt </label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="actorCheckbox" value="AngelinaJolie"> Angelina Jolie </label>
</div>

<div class="movie BradPitt AngelinaJolie">Mr and Mrs Smith</div>
<div class="movie BradPitt">Something with only Pitt in it</div>
<div class="movie AngelinaJolie">Something with only Angelina in it</div>
<div class="movie Joker">Something with clowns</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {

    var showElements = function() {
      $('.movie').hide(); // hide all .movie elements

      $('input[name=actorCheckbox]:checked').each(function() {
        $('.movie.' + $(this).val()).show();
      });
    }

    $("input[type=checkbox]").on("change", showElements);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much - this is my favourite answer for its simplicity. I think I was too fixated on only toggling the visibility of only divs that were related to the value of the checkbox selected - it is much easier to just hide all movie divs at the start of the function and re-evaluate for all each time the showElements function is invoked.

Answer (score 1):

To make it work I would suggest to make a few small changes:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var showElements = function() {
    var inputValue = []
    $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function() {
      inputValue.push($(this).val())
    })
    $('.movie').hide();
    $('.movie').filter(function() {
      for (var i = 0; i < inputValue.length; i++) {
        if ($(this).hasClass(inputValue[i])) {
          return $(this)
        }
      }
    }).show();
  }
  $("input[type=checkbox]").on("click", showElements);
});
```

I've also added the class `movie` to `<div class = "BradPitt AngelinaJolie">Mr and Mrs Smith</div>`

**Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var showElements = function() {
    var inputValue = []
    $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function() {
      inputValue.push($(this).val())
    })
    $('.movie').hide();
    $('.movie').filter(function() {
      for (var i = 0; i < inputValue.length; i++) {
        if ($(this).hasClass(inputValue[i])) {
          return $(this)
        }
      }
    }).show();
  }
  $("input[type=checkbox]").on("click", showElements);
});
```

```css
.BradPitt {
  display: none
}

.AngelinaJolie {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="actorCheckbox" value="BradPitt"> Brad Pitt </label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="actorCheckbox" value="AngelinaJolie"> Angelina Jolie </label>
</div>

<div class="movie BradPitt AngelinaJolie">Mr and Mrs Smith</div>
<div class="movie BradPitt">Troy</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this Carsten. I'm fairly inexperienced so this might be a more robust solution for reasons I can't understand, but I have chosen 04FS's answer because it appears simpler (It does not bloat the code with a for loop to build an array). I'm not sure if building an array has added benefits that I'm not clear on - if so, I'd love to understand more about it :) thanks!